# How to use grep to find the next 7 characters after "temp1"?

Tags: grep

how can i get "+45.0°C" if the following output was a file (http://paste.linuxthefish.net/4@raw)?

I can get it to one line by doing

```
sensors -A acpitz-virtual-0 > sen
grep temp1 ~/sen
```

but it still has a load of useless crap on it:

```
"temp1:        +42.0Â°C  (crit = +90.0Â°C)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer:
For instance these are the texts inside the file

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +45.0Â°C  (crit = +90.0Â°C)
temp2:        +45.0Â°C  (crit = +90.0Â°C)
```

To get the `+45.0Â°C` of temp1, use this command:

```
grep temp1 < theFileWithTemp.txt | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use egrep (or grep -e) to use regular expressions. With `.{7}` 7 arbitrary characters:

```
echo -e "temp1:\t+42.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)" | egrep -o "temp1:.{7}"
temp1:  +42.
```

With -o you restrict the output to your match. To cut off just the rest of the line:

```
 echo -e "temp1:\t+42.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)" | egrep -o "temp1:.{7}" | egrep -o ".{5}$"
```